# Using buildozer with Kivy 1.9.1-dev

Tags: android, kivy

I want to contribute to Kivy 1.9.1-dev.
Trying to debug on android, using buildozer, from `~/` I've tried:

```
git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy.git
cd kivy
python setup.py build_ext --inplace -f
```

then from `~/` I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

finally from `~/kivy-test/`

```
buildozer init
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

eventually I get the following error:

```
Detected compiler is unix
building 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions' extension
ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/navatm/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/navatm/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -fPIC -I/home/navatm/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include -I/home/navatm/code/kivy-test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.o
kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
#error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
   ^
error: command 'ccache' failed with exit status 1

# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Follow the instructions. `# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2`.

Comment: Done. See the updated output above.